# Push elements of an array to different keys using Javascript & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an array [0,1,2]. I'm trying to assign the array values to an JSON Object as image1:0, image2:1, image3:2, using Javascript but I'm getting confused. Please find my code here

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('EventController',function EventController($scope) {
   $scope.count = 0;  
   $scope.next = function() {
        var arr = [0,1,2];
        var result = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result.image1 = arr[i];
            result.image2 = arr[i];
            result.image3 = arr[i];
        }
        console.log(result)
   }
});
```

My expected result is Object {image1: 0, image2: 1, image3: 2}

But actual result coming is Object {image1: 2, image2: 2, image3: 2}

My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zvy2c/67/

Comment: [`for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result['image' + (i + 1)] = arr[i];
}`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rc54qd7t/)

Comment: Cool Tushar.. Awesome

Answer (score 2):

You may use the bracket operator for accessing the property

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result['image' + (i + 1)] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: @Tushar, you are faster in comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through `arr` and assigning the same value to all your properties. You set everything to `0`, then `1`, then `2`.

Forget about the `for` loop and just set the properties to whichever entry in the array you want:

```
var arr = [0,1,2];
var result = {
    image1: arr[0],
    image2: arr[1],
    image3: arr[2]
};
```

Comment: Did the OP say it needs to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('EventController',function EventController($scope) {
   $scope.count = 0;  
   $scope.next = function() {
        var arr = [0,1,2];
        var result = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result['image' + (i+1)] = arr[i];
        }
        console.log(result)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for loop as

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result['image'+i] = arr[i];
}
```